# Solvability of a Diophantine equation in mod 8 class

Tags: modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

How does one solve an equation of the form 
$$
3^a - b^3 \equiv 1 \ ({\rm mod}\ 8)?
$$

Comment: Note that $3^a \equiv 3 \bmod 8$ or $3^a \equiv 1 \bmod 8$

Answer (score 1):

If $a=2k$ , then $3^a=9^k\equiv 1\mod 8$. So, $b^3\equiv 0 \mod 8$. That is true,iff, $b$ is even
 Therefore, we have solutions when both $a$ and $b$ are even.

If $a=2k+1$, $3^a\equiv 3\mod 8$. So, $b^3\equiv 2 \mod 8$. But, you can check that $b^3$ can only give you 0, 1, -1, 3, -3 as remianders when divided by 8.

Comment: Perfect! $b^3\equiv 2 \mod 8 \implies b^3$ is even. However, when $b$ is even $b^3\equiv 0 \mod 8 $. Therefore, no solution to the problem when $a$ is odd!

Comment: Oh, yeah it is a way better finish, I was too concentrated on cubic reminders)